# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes even with whitelist_attributes=false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, strong-parameters

I'm migrating from rails 2.3 to 3.2 and want to use `strong_parameters`. I changed `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` config `true` to `false`, but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 2):

Check `application.rb` and all environment files for `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer`, this should be removed and then it works.